# What is wrong with this incremental logic for a game scoring system?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I am incrementing and decrementing a score (specifically `scoreVar` variable) in my game in JavaScript and HTML it does not work as it should, it does not increment always when a right answer is given (often staying at zero or last inputted number) or neither decrement when a wrong answer is given in the same way, is there anything I am doing wrong here?

I have updated the below codes to add a new checking aspect, that if the score goes below 0 it should then stay at zero. This kind of works, but each time it will get stuck at -1 instead when doing this and cannot figure out why? I think it was a good attempted fix though that shows more what I am aiming to do and that this question is not related to type but more a single variable (scoreVar) which I am having issues with incrementing and decrementing.

At the moment I can't see enough evidence working, documentated and theoretical that the type of the text box impacts a variable that is not specifically assigned or manipulated by the text box, unless I missed something there?

Please note the initial code, does not run, but the code below is more detailed and it does. I just put that initial code there for simplicity sake / to make the reading of my problem easier.

```js
if (answerInput.value == summation)
{
scoreVar++;
            if (scoreVar >= 0) {
                scoreElem.innerHTML = "Score: " + scoreVar;
            }
            if (scoreVar <= 0)
            {
                scoreVar = 0;
                scoreElem.innerHTML = "Score: " + scoreVar;
            }
            if (scoreVar < 0)
            {
                timeleft = 0;
            }
}


else if (answerInput.value != summation) {
scoreVar--;
            if (scoreVar >= 0){
            scoreElem.innerHTML = "Score: " + scoreVar;
            }
            if (scoreVar <= 0)
            {
                scoreVar = 0;
                scoreElem.innerHTML = "Score: " + scoreVar;
            }
            if (scoreVar < 0)
            {
                timeleft = 0;
            }
}
```

So from here I have tried to look at the documentation specifically, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment I see you have postfix and prefix, but I don't believe as attempted prefix is the right fix here? Unless I am not coding it in the right way in its entirety.

My other theory involves in the code below, that the order and speed of what happens when a correct or incorrect answer is given, is overlapping? For example I answer four questions quickly in succession as erratically as possible, where the issue usually occurs, say 3 wrong and 1 correct, the score then does not update quickly enough / to the right increment or decrement.

The full project code is listed below for a better context of what is happening:

```js
const random = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;

const select = (selector) => document.querySelector(selector);

function mathFunc(x, y, c) {
    if (c === "+") return x + y;
    else if (c === "-") return x - y;
    else if (c === "*") return x * y;
    else if (c === "/") return x / y; //Is the "/" in this in respect of the " " one only actually doing anything mathematical?
    return -1;
}

/**
 * Our main game starts here.
 */
function main() {
    let num1;
    let num2;
    let summation;
    let summation2;
    let operators = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]; //Is the "/" in this in respect of the " " one only actually doing anything mathematical?
    let op;
    let scoreVar = 0;

    let questionElem = select(".questionText");
    let resultElem = select(".result");
    let answerInput = select(".answer");
    let scoreElem = select(".score")

    scoreElem.innerHTML = "Score: " + scoreVar;



    answerInput.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            select(".Btn").click();
        }
    });

    select(".Btn").addEventListener("click", handleSubmit);

    function handleSubmit() {
        resultElem.innerHTML = "Button has been clicked and text = " + answerInput.value;

        if (answerInput.value == summation) {
            resultElem.innerHTML = "Answer is " + summation + " so you are correct!";
            console.log("Answer inputted: " + answerInput.value);
            answerInput.value = "";
            new Audio("correct.mp3").play();
            scoreVar++;
            console.log("Score: " + scoreVar);
            if (scoreVar >= 0) {
                scoreElem.innerHTML = "Score: " + scoreVar;
            }
            if (scoreVar <= 0)
            {
                scoreVar = 0;
                scoreElem.innerHTML = "Score: " + scoreVar;
            }
            if (scoreVar < 0)
            {
                timeleft = 0;
            }
            setTimeout(function(){ (resultElem.innerHTML = ""); }, 1000);
            questionAsk();
        }
        else if (answerInput.value != summation) {
            resultElem.innerHTML = "Answer is " + summation + " so you are NOT correct!";
            console.log("Answer inputted: " + answerInput.value);
            answerInput.value = "";
            new Audio("incorrect.mp3").play();
            scoreVar--;
            console.log("Score: " + scoreVar);
            if (scoreVar >= 0){
            scoreElem.innerHTML = "Score: " + scoreVar;
            }
            if (scoreVar <= 0)
            {
                scoreVar = 0;
                scoreElem.innerHTML = "Score: " + scoreVar;
            }
            if (scoreVar < 0)
            {
                timeleft = 0;
            }

            setTimeout(function(){ (resultElem.innerHTML = ""); }, 1000);
            questionAsk();
        }
    }

    function questionAsk() {
        op = operators[random(0, 4)];
        num1 = random(1, 10);
        num2 = random(1, 10);
        summation = Math.round(mathFunc(num1, num2, op));
        summation2 = (mathFunc(num1, num2, op));


        let question = "What is " + num1 + " " + op + " " + num2 + "?";

        questionElem.innerText = question;

        console.log(question);
        console.log("Summation / Answer with rounding = " + summation)
        console.log("Summation / Answer without rounding = " + summation2)


    }

    let interval;

    function timer() {
        let timeleft = 350;

        if (interval) clearInterval(interval);

        interval = setInterval(function () {
            if (timeleft <= 0) {
                document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "GAME OVER!";
                document.getElementsByClassName("questionText")[0].innerHTML = "";
                document.getElementsByClassName("result")[0].innerHTML = "";
                document.getElementsByClassName("answer")[0].style.visibility = "hidden"; //alt is visible rather than hidden to show it again!
                document.getElementsByClassName("Btn")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
                clearInterval(interval);
            } else {
                document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft + " seconds remaining";
            }
            timeleft -= 1;
        }, 1000);
    }
    timer();

    questionAsk();
}

main();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Rubik', Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Calcla</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik">
</head>

<body>

  <p class="questionText"></p>
  <label>
    <input type="number" class="answer"/>
</label>
  <button class="Btn">Submit</button>
  <div class="result"></div>
  <br>
  <div id="countdown"></div>
  <div class="score"></div>



  <script src="math.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: are you comparing strings  with numbers ?

Comment: For the context of this question, the score specifically, `scoreVar` is numbers only throughout the entire code except when it is concatenated with `scoreElem`, but this should not affect it? So no for the score, I am not comparing strings to numbers.

Comment: It says `<input type="number" ` something I am missing here? It indicates you can 'only' enter a number in this field, unless I am mistaken? Note this number in this field has nothing to do with the variable that indicates the score `scoreVar`

Comment: Could you perhaps put this as an answer, the short comments are too ambiguous here and I am not entirely sure what you are getting at? It clearly says input type number to me, a number is being entered. This is not even a factor with the scoring, as they don't overlap, especially with the input. Score is just a sole number on its own.

Comment: I checked it using typeof. It indicates `undefined` not a string as indicated? But if you could give a more detailed answer it would be much appericiated.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the bug you mentioned with the snippet you posted. I play for more than 1 minute and everything seems fine, updates happen instantly. 

Comment: If you get a question wrong and your score is 0, `scoreVar` becomes -1, meaning you have to increment twice before getting back to one. It does this on my computer but not on StackOverflow which is strange. But as you can see anyway it still has odd behaviour around 0, -1 and so forth. I never want it to go to -1 and my current updated logic should prevent that but it does not.

Comment: Don't provide a full project, provide a [MCVE], too much code makes it hard to pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is there:

```
answerInput.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => 
  {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) 
    {
    event.preventDefault();
    select(".Btn").click();
    }
  });
```

I think using the KeyUp makes the preventDefault ineffective

Otherwise I revisited all your code, you should refocus your functions on a single technical subject, your code would be more readable

voila:

```js
const
  mF         = document.forms['my-form']
, TimeEnd    = 'TimeOut'
, TimeEndEvt = new Event(TimeEnd)
, Question   = 
    { score    : 0
    , response : 0
    , timOut   : 0
    }
, displayTime = seconds => mF.countDown.textContent = !!seconds ? `${seconds} seconds remaining` : 'GAME OVER!'
, timmer      = ( timeleft , displayFn = displayTime ) =>
    {
    const
      one_Sec = 1000
    , tim = 
      { target : 0 
      , intRef : 0
      };
    tim.target = Date.now() + (timeleft * one_Sec)
    displayFn(timeleft)

    tim.Ref = setInterval(()=>
      {
      let sec = Math.floor((tim.target - Date.now())  / one_Sec)

      if (sec>0) displayFn(sec)
      else
        {
        clearInterval( tim.Ref )
        displayFn(0)
        mF.dispatchEvent(TimeEndEvt)   // send End Event on form
        }
      }, 500)
    }
, newQuestion =_=>
    {
    const
      operators = '+-*/'
    , random    = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min
      ;
    let
      op = operators[random(0, 4)]
    , n1 = random(1, 10)
    , n2 = random(1, 10)
      ;
    mF.question.textContent = `${n1} ${op} ${n2}`
    switch (op)
      {
      case '+':  Question.response = n1 + n2;  break;
      case '-':  Question.response = n1 - n2;  break;
      case '*':  Question.response = Math.round(n1 * n2);  break;
      case '/':  Question.response = Math.round(n1 / n2);  break;
      }
    console.clear()
    console.log( `answer is ${Question.response}`)
    mF.answer.value = ''
    mF.answer.focus()
    }
, CheckAnswser =_=>
    {
    let resp = Question.response
      , answ = mF.answer.valueAsNumber
      , Good = ( resp == answ )
      ;  
    Question.score +=  Good ? +1 : -1
    mF.score.textContent  = `Score: ${Question.score}`
    mF.result.textContent = `Answer is: ${resp}, so you are ${Good?'':'Not '}correct! `

    clearTimeout( Question.timOut )
    Question.timOut = setTimeout(()=>{  mF.result.innerHTML = '&nbsp;'},3000)
    }
, haveAnswer = e =>
    {
    e.preventDefault()
    CheckAnswser()
    newQuestion()
    }


newQuestion()  // start Questionning !
timmer(60)    // set timer delay...

mF.onsubmit = haveAnswer
mF.answer.onkeydown = e =>
  {
  if ( e.key === 'Enter'    // some keybords have  different return keys codes
  && mF.reportValidity() )
      haveAnswer(e)
  }

mF.addEventListener(TimeEnd, () =>  // use custom event to detect timer End
  {
  mF.btSubmit.disabled = true
  mF.answer.disabled   = true
  mF.answer.blur()
  mF.answer.value       = ''
  mF.question.innerHTML = '&nbsp;'
  console.clear()
  }, false)
```

```css
* {
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size   : 24px;
  }
output  {
  display   : block;
  font-size : 2em;
  margin    : 0 .7em;
  }
input {
  display    : inline-block;
  width      : 10em;
  margin     : .7em 1em;
  text-align : center;
  }
output[name="result"] {
  font-size : 1em;
  color     : lightslategrey;
  }
```

```html
<form name="my-form">
  <output name="question"> </output>
  <input  name="answer" type="number" value="">
  <button name="btSubmit" type="submit">Submit </button>
  <output name="result">&nbsp;</output>
  <output name="countDown">countDown </output>
  <output name="score">score </output>
</form>
```

Comment: Again though, the score system I am using has literally null, as in absolute nothing to do with the input box. The input box is not incrementing or decrementing the variable only the variables in the code specifically for `scoreVar` I have gone through the code immensely I can't see anywhere `scoreVar` has been used for the text input box. Unless I am missing something here?

Comment: But scoreVar again is using only a number, I just really can't see how the string comes into it, if a string never comes into the variable, literally at all, additionally from my own tests of `scoreVar` not the input box (you have ignored this variable entirely which confuses me even more) anyhow you said learn the basics, so I will re-read a book and report back. I will keep updating the question with what I have learned if anything new hopefully. But again, its for `scoreVar` I mean can you definitely see this in the code? I was really clear in the initial question about it.

Comment: I understand your remarks completely, I just can't see for example how the input is affecting `scoreVar` I understand there are more errors these will take me a long time to fix. My issue mainly at the moment was with the logic I was using for the scoring system. I put this clearly in the initial question, I was not looking for a full code review, which is why I separated the scoring logic separate to the main code.

Comment: Although I admit this answer gives an indication of what is wrong in my code, despite my extreme best efforts to correlate, I can't see how it is related to my initial question.

Comment: Thanks will give it a look in a couple of hours/tomorrow hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let scoreVar = 0;

    const btn1function = () => {
        scoreVar++;

        document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Score: " + scoreVar;
        console.log("Score: " + scoreVar);

        if (scoreVar >= 0) {
            document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Score: " + scoreVar;
            console.log("Score: " + scoreVar);
        }
        if (scoreVar <= -1)
        {
            document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Game Over";
            scoreVar = 0;
            console.log("Score: " + scoreVar);
        }

    };

    const btn2function = () => {
        scoreVar--;

        document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Score: " + scoreVar;
        console.log("Score: " + scoreVar);

        if (scoreVar >= 0) {
            document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Score: " + scoreVar;
            console.log("Score: " + scoreVar);
        }
        if (scoreVar <= -1)
        {
            document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Game Over";
            scoreVar = 0;
            console.log("Score: " + scoreVar);
        }


    };
```

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Rubik', Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: lighter;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik">

<button onclick="btn1function()">Increase</button>
<button onclick="btn2function()">Decrease</button>
<p id="score"></p>
```

So I added my own temporary solution to this for now so the answer is easier to understand for beginners. I still selected the above as an answer though, as technically its a more bug free way to do it, which was initially causing me issues. This code is more just for basic understanding of the logic than the 'best' solution.